# Disable UITableViewCell edit mode with rxswift

Tags: ios, swift2, rx-swift

I bind my dataSource to tableview using `rxswift`, but by default cells are editable when I am doing like that, how can I disable that functionality?

Here the example of tableview what I got:

[image: here the example of tableview what I got]

Comment: Hey @Petros, How you disabled edit mode with RxSwift?

Comment: @Abhishek

`tableView.rx_setDelegate(self)`

and 

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}`

Answer (score 3):

Are you using RxDataSources? you can configure you're dataSource as followed

```
dataSource.canEditRowAtIndexPath = {dataSource, indexPath in false }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand well your problem. But if you simply want to disable edit mode on your cells, add this code :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here the code example

```
       viewModel
            .fetchMockServicesDataSource()
            .asObservable()
            .bindTo(mockServiceTableView.rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier("mockCell", cellType: MockTableViewCell.self)) { row, element, cell in
                cell.updateCell(element)
            }
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

but anyway I found the working solution
I need to add these parts

```
mockServiceTableView.rx_setDelegate(self)


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}
```